# Multiply pandas dataframe and dict after date truncation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import datetime
data = [[random.random(), random.random()] for i in range(9)]
index = pd.date_range(start=datetime.date(2019,1,1), end=datetime.date(2019,3,5), freq='W')
columns = ['col1', 'col2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
```

That is

```
                col1      col2
2019-01-06  0.027467  0.506598
2019-01-13  0.329616  0.558430
2019-01-20  0.850979  0.874664
2019-01-27  0.859704  0.168140
2019-02-03  0.399097  0.229954
2019-02-10  0.239516  0.626095
2019-02-17  0.450974  0.668491
2019-02-24  0.202464  0.434521
2019-03-03  0.337609  0.705639
```

I also have a dictionary that looks like

```
multipliers = {datetime.date(2019,1, 1): 4, datetime.date(2019,2,1): 5, datetime.date(2019,3, 1): 2}
```

What I'd like to do is return a dataframe where both entries in both columns are multiplied by the value in `multipliers` that correspond to the same month.  If the dataframe had the same dates as multipliers, then I could just do `df.mul(multipliers, axis=0)`, but that's not the case here.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  I could use a for loop and compare the dates after truncation, but that almost certainly isn't the fastest/ most efficient way to do it.

---

**Alternatively**, the multipliers could be in the form of a dataframe themselves.  An easy way to get this for my example above would be

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(multipliers.values(), multipliers.keys(), columns=['mults'])
```

which would produce a dataframe that looks like

```
            mults
2019-01-01    4
2019-02-01    5
2019-03-01    2
```

Even in this form, I'm not sure what a good way to multiply this dataframes together is.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you won't get anything much faster than this:

`for date, mul in multipliers.items():
    df[df.index.month == date.month] *= mul`